# How to let \in or \notin appear above the underline when clicking the screen?

Tags: beamer, formatting

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{1.use$\in$or$\notin$.}
(1)Suppose $A$ are the set of the countries in Asia,then：\\
China\rule[-2pt]{0.8cm}{0.5pt}$A$,USA\rule[-2pt]{0.8cm}{0.5pt}$A$,\\ 
India\rule[-2pt]{0.8cm}{0.5pt}$A$,UK\rule[-2pt]{0.8cm}{0.5pt}$A$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I try to use \pause & \invisible, but it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\visible` or `\temporal` for that. Have a look.
To tell the truth, i think those rules are *just ugly*, and i hope you just wanted to say where things are belonging.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\newcommand{\savespace}{ \rule[-2pt]{0.5cm}{0.5pt} }
\newcommand{\textin}{~$\in$~}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{1.use $\in$ or $\notin$.}
(1) Suppose $A$ are the set of the countries in Asia,then：
\begin{itemize}
\item China\visible<2->{\textin}$A$,
\item India\temporal<3>{\savespace}{\savespace\hspace{-0.6cm}\textin}{\textin}$A$
\item <4> another item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can find more information in the [beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) manual.

As you can see, i added some *negative space* to place the `\in` roughly in the middle of the rule. You can automate this, calculating this spacing (it is dependent on the fontsize, and the width of the material pulled). But as i said, those rules are *soo* ugly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, the second item is the result I want, but not good enough. Never mind the ugly rule. :)

Comment: Not good enough? Can you be more specific, about what you want to have differently?

Comment: The position of A moves slightly after \in appear. Anyway, it doesn't matter. Thank you !